# How stop thread with infinite loop in finally block

Tags: java, multithreading

Sorry for my English.

I have a Thread with method:

```
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      System.out.println( "Hello world" );
      Thread.sleep( 10 );
    }
    catch( InterruptedException e )
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      while( true )
        System.out.println( "FINALLYYY" );
    }
  }
```

and I suggest, that this thread never can be stopped!
After calling methods interrupt or stop - in finally block thread will start infinity loop.

How I can force the thread to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...
I Found next solution:

```
worker.interrupt();
while( worker.isAlive() )
  worker.stop();
```

It's not ideal solution, but in my case, it's best...
Every call worker.stop - throw unchecked exception "ThreadDeath" and each finally block will be "skiped". 
It should stop the thread.

Answer (score 1):

The Thread stop and interrupt methods are not the best way to solve this problem. Add a boolean variable to your thread and check it in your while statement.

For example:

```java
  private volatile boolean keepGoing = true;

  public void stopTheThread() {
      keepGoing = false;
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      System.out.println( "Hello world" );
      Thread.sleep( 10 );
    }
    catch( InterruptedException e )
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      while( keepGoing )
        System.out.println( "FINALLYYY" );
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you don't put volatile in the keepGoing var your loop could end never.

Comment: @David ten Hove Yes, I know about it.... But I can't control or validate the code.. Because it's "external custom user's code", which should be executed on our server..

Comment: @EugeneChipachenko If that's the case, I think there is no solid way of stopping the thread in Java

Comment: @CarlosVerdes Good catch. I missed that

Answer (score 0):

In your current set up, you could stop the thread by calling the `interrupt()` method on the `Thread` that is executing.

Either way, to allow the Thread to terminate gracefully, you will have to expose a way to terminate that thread, either by exposing the thread so it can be interrupted, or by providing a 'kill switch' in the way suggested by David ten Hove.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may try to control how the user's thread is executed (at least while you control user's threads execution). For instance, you can use **Future** from concurrency package (don't forget to handle exceptions):

   ```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future task = executor.submit(usersThread);

    try {
        task.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } finally {
        task.cancel(true);
    }
   ```
2. If you can't control the code inside the Thread, then you may control the code, which is used from it. For instance, consider the following approaches:

   - If you can run that Thread in a groovy context, then you can reassign methods, which are called from the Thread. Actually, you can deny everything and pass every call through your custom handler for unknown methods.
   - If you are sure, what is called from the Thread, then you can pick up some hijacks (consider an example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002450/how-to-interrupt-an-infinite-loop)).